# LINQ - filter collection inside collection

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have the following classes:

```
class Parent
{
    bool Gender { get; set; }
    List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}


class Child
{
    bool Gender { get; set; }
    List<Child> GrandChildren { get; set; }
}


class GrandChild
{
    bool Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Using linq, can anyone help me filter a Parent object by returning a `List<Child>` where each Child has `Gender == false` and each Child's GrandChild has `Gender == false`?

I've managed to return a `List<GrandChild>` but I really need the hierarchy to be maintained.

Comment: Do you mean you *only* want the children to be returned where their gender is false and all their children have a gender of false?

Comment: As a side note, I'd suggest you to change `Gender` property to Enum {Male,Female} because `Gender=true/false` is pretty unclear to understand...

Comment: I love Gender being a bool. So is male represented by `true` and female by `false`? Like in real life? ;-P

Comment: :) Gender was just an example.. thanks for all the quick answers

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough.. The queries do not filter the grandchildren.. they only return a list<Child> that have Gender==false GrandChild objects. But the GrandChildren collection still isn't filtered.. it still returns Gender == false and true GranChild

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague. Here's a solution which rebuilds the children and grandchildren lists, I wasn't sure if I needed the child.GrandChildren.All(gc => !gc.Gender) so I left it out for clarity:

```
parents.Select(parent => new Parent
{
  Gender = parent.Gender,
  Children = parent.Children.Where(child => !child.Gender).Select(child => new Child
    {
      Gender = false,
      GrandChildren = child.GrandChildren.Where(gc => !gc.Gender).ToList()
    }
  ).ToList()
})
```

Answer (score 17):

You're looking for

```
.Where(p => p.Children.All(c => !c.Gender && c.GrandChildren.All(g => !g.Gender))
```

Comment: I want to filter out all the objects that have Gender == true but still maintain the same structure

Comment: @teknoplast: What do you mean?

Comment: i want to filter both List<Child> and List<Grandchildren> so that Gender == false. with your code it returns a filtered List<Child> but the GrandChildren isn't being filtered

Comment: You'll need to clone your `Child` objects, then call `RemoveAll` on the clones' Lists to get rid of unwanted grandchildren.

Comment: so why is this the accepted answer and not mine which does exactly this? :)

Answer (score 3):

- help me filter a Parent object
- by returning a `List<Child>`
- where each Child has Gender == false
- and each Child's GrandChild has Gender == false?

Translated literally:

```
List<Child> results =
(
  from c in theParent.Children
  where !c.Gender
  where c.GrandChildren.Any(gc => !gc.Gender)
  select c
).ToList()
```

---

Based on your comments, what you really want:

```
List<Parent> result = 
(
from p in Parents
where !p.Gender
select new Parent()
{
  Gender = p.Gender,
  Children = 
  (
    from c in p.Children
    where !c.Gender
    select new Child()
    {
      Gender = c.Gender,
      GrandChildren =
      (
        from gc in c.GrandChildren
        where !gc.Gender
        select new GrandChild()
        {
          Gender = gc.Gender
        }
      ).ToList()
    }
  ).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var filteredParents = 
    from p in parents
    where p.Children.All(child => !child.Gender &&
                         child.GrandChildren.All(grandChild => !grandChild.Gender))
    select p;
```

Using `All` method here ensures that the predicate passed as an argument to that method is true for all elements in given sequence.

Given code checks for each parent that has `All` children with (`Gender = false` and also having `All` grand children `Gender = false`).